# Mule Batch application throws org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentInitException: ClassNotFoundException: org.mule.api.process.ProcessAdapter

Tags: mule, mule-studio

I am trying to run Mule Batch Code and getting below error when mule is trying to start an application:

> org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentInitException: ClassNotFoundException: org.mule.api.process.ProcessAdapter.

Which jars or mule module I am missing for `org.mule.api.process.ProcessAdapter`?

Is this enterprise license issue?

I am tried my mule code in both in mule studio and mule standalone but getting the same error.

Please provide input.

Comment: which versions of Mule Runtime are you using in your project? Because after a lot of search, I could find only one ProcessAdapter, and it is `org.mule.api.devkit.ProcessAdapter`

Answer (score 0):

After backtracking to various versions (and actually downloading jar from each iteration from this https://repository.mulesoft.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/org/mule/tools/devkit/mule-devkit-annotations/) I could find the class(actually an abstract interface) you are referring to in the mule-devkit-annotations but the last iteration that included the `org.mule.api.process` was 3.3.2 and it was dropped after 3.4.0

In mule-devkit-annotations-3.3.2:

`public abstract interface ProcessAdapter<O>
{
  public abstract <T> ProcessTemplate<T, O> getProcessTemplate();
}`

However, I could find the same Interface in mule-module-devkit-support.jar (I was using 3.6.1)

In mule-module-devkit-support-3.6.1.jar:

`public interface ProcessAdapter<O>
{
    <T> ProcessTemplate<T, O> getProcessTemplate();
}`